# Send an email with server based service which can dispatch an email via SMTP

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, servlets, smtp

I understand that I can send an email through **Outlook** using **javascript** and with **mailto** tag also. **mailto** tag will also open the default mailing client which will install on PC (did not to use it that all), however in my current situation I did not want to use it.

I want to create a webservice in **Java** or **.Net**. I can call the same web service with javascript or ajax that can dispatch an e-mail via SMTP.

Please let me know how to create a web service. Any idea will be helpful.
Thanks.

[Useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647931/sending-email-from-html-using-javascript-without-default-outlook)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling an SMTP provider's web services API from javascript of ajax.  This would require the account credentials to be sent from the end user's browser, where they could easily be compromised.  Better would be to call the SMTP provider's web services API from your server.

Comment: @mti2935 totally agree, I will call web service through javascript or ajax and then web service will use SMTP provider's web services API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because your are using an applet already it would be easier just to do the e-mail method in java and call via JavaScript (this may throw unsigned applet warning at start). 
Create a method in java that will send the message via smtp

Helpful links:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

[Sending Email via gmail smtp server in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597616/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-java)

Comment: i am not using an applet. i am using html page to call web service